# Can anyone tell me what is going on under the hood of the Shift( ) & Unshift( ) array methods in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods

I would like to know exactly how the functions are created. I would like to know so that I can study and recreate them myself. I know that they are there for us to use, but I want to break them down to first principals and know why and how they work the way they do.

Comment: You're welcome: https://github.com/v8/v8-git-mirror/blob/8a378f46d52ce64578c71313ed76a67592fbf63c/src/array.js#L709

Comment: @zerkms This is wonderful! Thank you!

Comment: @zerkms Why don't you add this as an answer?

Comment: @LuisSieira it's just a link http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/145588

Answer (score 0):

See the [ECMAScript Language Specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/),

- section [22.1.3.21 - Array.prototype.shift()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.shift)
- section [22.1.3.28 - Array.prototype.unshift()](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.unshift)

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this could help you about **unshift()** method:

```js
let arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

let newArray = []

//foo is like unshift()
foo('start')

function foo(_item){
  newArray[0] = _item
  arr.forEach((x,i) => toArray(i))
}

function toArray(_i){
  newArray[_i + 1] = arr[_i]
}
console.log(newArray)
```